# Access variables in C# from javascript when map(browser) is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Purpose of my application is to integrate leaflet map in wpf app. I have used webbrowser control in xaml and used webbrowser.Navigate("html file path") to load the source in webbrowser.

Now, when i click on map, a popup appears in javascript which displays latitude and longitude of the clicked point on map, for this purpose,  I used map.on("click") in javascript. Now, I want to access latitude and longitude in xaml.cs file to apply some functionality. My main question is, how can I access those latitude and longitude variables from javascript in C#?
 One of the approach is to write webbrowser.InvokeScript("function_name") but I don't know how can I invoke map.on("click") function in C# to get latitude and longitude.

Please help...